# Inverse Laplace transform of a rational function with third order polynominal denominator, using Sympy

Tags: math, sympy, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I'm trying to do the inverse Laplace transform of a generalized rational function of the form:
D/(A*s**2 + B*s + C)
using sympy.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import inverse_laplace_transform as ilt
from sympy.abc import s, t
var('A:D')
eq = D/(A*s**2 + B*s + C)
solution = ilt(eq, s, t)
```

Knowing the answer from mathematical analysis to be:

```
-(A (e^(t (-1/2 sqrt(C^2-4 B)-C/2))-e^(t (1/2 sqrt(C^2-4 B)-C/2))))/sqrt(C^2-4 B)
```

But the sympy will NOT yield a solution and the code will stuck in an infinity CPU process with no specific gain.
But putting the eq like this:

```
eq = B/((s - A)**2 + B**2)
```

sympy will result in the equation of the form like this:

```
-I*(I*exp(t*im(B))*sin(t*(re(B) - im(A))) - exp(t*im(B))*cos(t*(re(B) - im(A)))
+ I*exp(-t*im(B))*sin(t*(re(B) + im(A))) + exp(-t*im(B))*cos(t*(re(B) + im(A))))
*exp(t*re(A))*Heaviside(t)/2
```

Which is not what I would need to.
Any suggestions on how to make sympy yield to such a human readable answer?

Comment: If you know that A and B are real, set them so when you create them (`A, B = symbols("A:B", real=True)`).

Comment: Yes @asmeurer that worked for the case:
`eq = B/((s - A)**2 + B**2)`. But still the main issue remains:
if I introduce `A, B, C = symbols("A:C", real=True)`, with `eq = B/(s**2 - 2*A + C**2)`, the inverse Laplace transform will result in nothing but infinite CPU cycles. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you keyboard interrupt it after it's run for a while and paste the traceback somewhere?

Comment: @asmeurer 
here you are:
[http://pastebin.com/6RyhxFQR]
it is the keyboard break for:
`from sympy import *; from sympy import s, t; from sympy import inverse_laplace_transform as ilt; A, B = symbols("A:B"); eq = 1/(s**2 - A*2*s + B**2 ); ilt(eq, s, t)`

Comment: It says the paste has been removed.

Comment: here is another paste: [http://pastebin.com/FREAHWSM]

Comment: @asmeurer edit: A and B were actually introduced with `A, B = symbols("A:B", real = True)`, not `A, B = symbols("A:B")`, as you mentioned before.

Comment: BTW, `A*s**2 + B*s + C` is a second order polynomial, not a third.

Comment: Yes it is. But they both seem to suffer in the same way.
May be working on the second order polynomial yields an easier answer.

Comment: Oh, SO is putting the last `]` as part of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the traceback, this looks like a legitimate bug. You should report it in the [SymPy issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/).